# How to make JSESSIONID and other cookie secure?

Tags: cookies, tomcat7, session-cookies, jsessionid

I used the below code in `WEB-INF/web.xml`  but `JSESSIONID`cookie is still not secure. I am doing something wrong because in my application we are using Spring 3.x for session management. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```xml
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>  
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989396/forcing-tomcat-to-use-secure-jsessionid-cookie-over-http and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553017/setting-httponly-and-secure-in-web-xml.

Comment: it's working, thanks